# Don't MiTM me please

Tags: bash, networking

To first understand how MiTM works I've made a few MiTM scripts, but this time I wanted to defend myself against such attacks. I'm unsure if my idea even works. The code seems to be working but I make a few assumptions and I'm not sure if those are correct.

**Assumptions**

1. When I do a `traceroute` the IP of the Attacker is in the route.
2. When I trace the route, and there is not a router device in my route it means an attacker(laptop) is listening on my connection
3. When I the attacker does an `ARP-Spoof`, the ARP-table has duplicate values.

**Code issues**

- I have this long `python -c "command"` it feels a bit silly to do in `bash`

---

Any review is welcome!

**Plus** I would be happy if anyone has additional information on how to prevent MiTM attacks.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

route_checker() {
    private_route=$(python -c 'import re; import subprocess; from ipaddress import IPv4Address; print([ip for ip in re.findall(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", subprocess.Popen(["traceroute", "-n", "8.8.8.8"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]) if IPv4Address(bytearray(ip)).is_private])' | tr --delete []\')
    echo "Your private route = $private_route"
    echo "Checking the safety of route: $private_route"

    echo ""
    echo "Starting nmap scan"
    OLD_IFS=$IFS
    IFS=', ' read -ra IP <<< "$private_route"
    for ip in "${IP[@]}"; do
    echo "Checking ip adress $ip:"
    os_scan=$(nmap -A -T4 "$ip")
    if [[ "$os_scan" =~ "broadband router" ]]
    then
        echo "[*] Warning! No router found."
    else
        echo "[*] Safe! A router was found."
    fi
    done
    IFS=$OLD_IFS
}

arp_checker() {
    if [[ $(arp -an | awk '{print $4}' | sort | uniq -c | grep -v ' 1 ') ]]
    then
    echo "[*] Warning! You are being spoofed"
    else
    echo "[*] Safe! Did not find any duplicate ARP values"
    fi
}

main() {
    echo "@Ludisposed"
    echo ""
    echo "Checking for ARP spoofing"
    arp_checker

    echo ""
    echo "Checking if we have a safe private route"
    route_checker
}

main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A few words about assumptions:

1. You're assuming that `arp` is installed. This is definitely not true for my system. `arp` as well as other "core network tools" like `ifconfig` have been superseded by `ip`. The more modern equivalents are `ip neigh show` and `ip addr`. The obsolescense is explicitly mentioned on the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/arp)
2. IIUC (because `traceroute` isn't available on my arch) similar considerations apply for `traceroute`. Also do note that you should be able to use the same idea as for the arp-check in the creation of `private_route`:

   ```
   route = $(tracepath -n 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $2}')
   private_route = # consider ipcalc or use $route as a smaller input to python
   ```

#### Final considerations:

You're inconsistent in the indentation of block scopes. In `arp_checker` the then and else block are indented, in `route_checker` they are, but the for loop body is not.
I strongly recommend indenting every block to increase readability.

Aside from that: Good job of not falling into common traps like:

- not double-quoting variables
- not using subshells
- using unsafe condition checks
- missing a shebang

From what I can see, this is a well-crafted script :)

Comment: I like your ideas. And me assuming so much about the machine is defenitly a flaw. One question though, does `ip neigh show` is the new norm because of `ipv6` implementation?

Comment: @Ludisposed that seems highly likely. I haven't deeply investigated there, TBH.

Comment: I'm guessing, since `ipv6 arp` is called `Neighbor Solicitation`.  It seems likely to me.